# I'm getting the network response, but CORS is not allowing it to enter

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I'm doing an API get request via axios to an Exchange Rates API

```
axios.get('https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD').then(res=>console.log('res',res)).catch(err => console.log('err',err))
```

And I'm getting the correct answer in the network[image: Response of the API request]

But this is what shows on in my console for de ERR of the get request [image: console]

I've researched that CORS message and all they say is, that you have to configure your server to accept the authorization header, but thats not an API to my server, it's a third party's server

What can I do?

UPDATE

I changed from "axios" from js "fetch" and it worked! I think maybe it was a default axios configuration that was causing the problem

Comment: If you don't control the API, you'll have to put a proxy between you and it that will add the right headers.

Comment: I changed from "axios" from js "fetch" and it worked! I think maybe it was a default axios configuration. Thanks anyway bro!

Comment: I"d suggest you look at the network trace in the Chrome debugger network tab for the outgoing request and compare the jsFetch request with the axios request.  You will be able to see what is different in the two requests and that will likely be the first step in explaining what the real problem was here.  And, there is probably an axios option that will make things work properly too.  That would be a "real" answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done in a browser application(cross is only for browsers).

It is a 3rd party so the only way to send request is by not having an origin =>>
Have a server(nodejs application) sending the request in there and returning the response.

**You send a request to your server => server returns the response from the corss blocked** => done

Comment: I changed from "axios" from js "fetch" and it worked! I think maybe it was a default axios configuration. Thanks anyway bro!

Comment: very weird :)  anyway if you ever have problem with the REAL CORS this is the way to go :)
Feel free to accept the answer hehehe

Comment: I don't see how this answer is actually an answer to the question at all as it doesn't lead to a solution or an explanation.  The real problem is probably some missing configuration for axios that jsfetch defaults differently.  A real answer to this question would figure out what is missing from the axios request or configuration that allows it to work.  It is likely CORs related, but there are many settings in Axios for sending the proper request.